# Relocating inside the EU with pets

Tags: eu, relocation, pets, lithuania

I'm an expat partner and we will relocate from Germany to Lithuania.
We have two rabbits, one turtle and some fish.

What formals have I to do / to respect, to get them with us?

Comment: The following should answer your question : https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/127181/carrying-a-rabbit-from-france-to-austria/139097#139097

Comment: Thank you for this hint. But the answer for this question links to an "entry Austria" specific declaration (Austrian government), no EU in general (or Lithuania specific) is provided.

Comment: @MarkJohnson (because I forget this again and again...)

Comment: There is no general EU guideline, other that which needs a pet passport . You will have to look for a corresponding Lithuanian site for exact details.